# Share data between Local and Docker container in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob, microk8s

I was successfully able to share data between a docker container and host using

```
docker run -it -v /path/to/host/folder:/container/path image-name
```

Now I am trying to run this docker image through a Kubernetes cronjob every minute for which my yaml file is as follows :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: automation
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: automation
            image: localhost:32000/image-name:registry  
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

But here how do I share data between my local and k8s so as to basically replicate the `-v /path/to/host/folder:/container/path` functionality from the docker run command  ?
What should I add to my yaml file ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just playing with **one node** and need to map a volume from this node to a pod running in the same node, then you need to use a [hostPath volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).
In summary, your code will look like this :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: automation
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: automation
            image: localhost:32000/image-name:registry  
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /container/path
              name: test-volume
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: test-volume
            hostPath:
              # directory location on host
              path: /path/to/host/folder
              # this field is optional
              type: Directory
```

Warning, this will work only if you just have a **one node cluster**.

If you have a multi-node cluster, then you need to havec a look at distributed storage solution and how to use them with kubernetes.

Here is the [doc about volumes in K8S](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)